# Push notification for weather forecast in natural language

Tags: nlp, weather

I would like an app that sends a daily message containing a natural language description of my hyperlocal forecast. Preferably based on a computer system and not humans. See this Wikipedia article for reference of the desired complexity:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_generation

Comment: For what OS do you want this app on?

Comment: iOS would be nice. I need it to stay updated with my location changes too like Dark Sky.